# javascript code for getting the select option value

Tags: javascript

I am using the code to detect the value of selected option of the select box, i am using the following code and firefox, it is working fine, but on chrome and IE, it is throwing an error. I cannot use jquery here due to project constraints:

```
var regID= document.getElementById("tdd");
            if (regID != null || regID != 'undefined' || regID != undefined) {
                var passvalue = regID.options[regID.selectedIndex].value;
}

Error by Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Firefox is not throwing any error

Comment: `console.log(regID.options, regID.selectedIndex)` just before the `passvalue` line. We can't know anything without that information, and you might not need our help when you see it :) Also, the `if` condition is an overkill here, a simple `if (regID)` suffices (since `getElementById` can only return an object or `null`)

Comment: Either there are no options or `#tdd` is not a `<select>`.

Comment: what if tdd does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the `value` of the `<select>`:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kr6x7uh/
updated fiddle with the added check to see if your `<select>` is null: http://jsfiddle.net/7kr6x7uh/1/

html:

```
<select id="tdd">
    <option val="1">Option 1</option>
    <option val="2">Option 2</option>
    <option val="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById('tdd');
if (select){
    alert(tdd.value); //  in your case, do 'var passvalue = tdd.value;'
}
```

Comment: what if tdd  does not exist.

Comment: put an `if` check in there.  I'm giving you the basic concept of how to get the selected value of the `<select>`